# XAML ToolTip + IsHitTestVisible="False"

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, xaml

We need to have mouse clicks and drags "ignored" by our View1 but the ToolTip must still function in that view. The reason is View1 is above View2 in Z-Order, so View1 can tint View2 a red color and show a warning via ToolTip; however the ToolTip accompanying View1 will not work if IsHitTestVisible="False".

Anyone know a work around so the ToolTip will display on mouse move/over and the rest of mouse events are ignored by View1 and go to View2?

Thanks,

Sean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did which is not great:

```
    private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var parentWindow = Window.GetWindow(this);
        var source = PresentationSource.FromVisual(parentWindow) as HwndSource;

        source.AddHook(WndProc);
    }

    private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
    {
        // Handle messages... 
        if (msg == WM_MOUSEMOVE)
        {
        ...show tool tip if mouse is over it
        }
        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

If someone else is facing same problem, they may find it helpful. 
We had a requirement to disable few rows on datagrid, but at the same time allow ARROW key navigation on them. This is why we had to switch to `IsHitTestVisible` instead of controlling `IsEnabled` property. So we couldn't adopt to above solution of switching to `IsEnabled` property.

Here is how I ended up solving this issue. I created a new attached property `RowEnable` for `DataGridRow`. This attached property can be bind to a viewmodel property to control `virtual` enable and disablement. I also created a new style for `DataGridCell` where I am setting `IsHitTestVisible` to `false` based on the same viewmodel property. So, consider it like a row which mouse/keyboard can see, but can't see its cells/columns. This means now I can style the row based on new attached property `RowEnabled` to look disabled/enabled. At the same time, I can take view tooltips for these tows which are virtually disabled.

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Don't set the `IsHitTestVisible="False"` !

Just add those lines

```
IsEnable = false
ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True"
```

Comment: IsEnable changes the style of component.